# ayuda paginar aray json y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, array

buen dia, en mi index.html tengo una estructura para llamar por ajax a mi archivo .php en la cual obtengo una informacion por json y la proceso para luego delvoler con echo el resultado html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html', // El tipo de datos esperados del servidor. Valor predeterminado: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).
        url: '/../loadatos.php?f=fema',
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery('#spinner').show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery("#warp").html(data);
            jQuery('#spinner').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

luego en mi archivo .php tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
        function curl_get_contents($url){
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }
    $url = 'https://aadsds.com/api/online/?format=json';
    $data = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url));

   foreach ($data as $key) {    
            $disname = $key->name;
            $follow = $key->followers;
            $age = $key->age;
     ?>
       <div class="warp">
            <div><?=$disname?></div>
            .............
       </div>
     <?php                
  }
```

luego en mi index.html me muestra perfecto todo el resualtado, pero todo al mismo tiempo, miles de resultados, quiero paginar ese resultado bien sea con un simple boton "cargar mas" o scroll infinito tipo facebook, como puedo hacer? para ir cargando de 15 en 15 hasta llegar al final, gracias por sus sugerencias..

Answer (score 0):

intenta darle el scroll a este elemento en concreto. Aqui te pongo el codigo

```js
jQuery("#warp").css("width", "100%");
jQuery("#warp").css("height", "200px"); //aqui pon lo que más te sirva de altura
jQuery("#warp").css("overflow", "auto");
```

Comment: gracias por tu colaboracion, no es lo que estoy buscando pero me ayudo a cierta forma a implimentar algo parecido, lo que hice fue cargar todo el contenido y con una funcion oculte todos lis divs y los voy mostrando de XX a XX cantidad precionando un boton, pero igual estoy pendiente de alguna otra sugerencia